# How to get site title in power apps form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I need to use Power Apps to customize our library form, which will be used on many sites.

There is a choice field that needs to have the default value set to the current site's title.

Is there a way to retrieve this value?

Comment: Are you going to add this app on the site page using web part? If yes, you can pass query string with site title in app URL which you can read in your app using Param function. If You Are using customize List form,I don't think there is any Direct way to get site title.

Comment: Okay, I just need it for customizing the form. Thank you.@GaneshSanap

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to add this power app on the SharePoint site page using Power Apps web part, you can pass the site title as query string parameter to app URL while passing app URL to Power Apps web part.

Then you can read the query string parameter value in your app using `Param()` function.

**Documentation**: [Launch and Param functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-param)

---

If you are using Power Apps customized list/library form, I don't think there is any direct way to get the site title using formulas.